# ASP Site Input string was not in a correct format. After trying to upload image

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am currently trying to support one of our clients by fixing their CMS running on a hosted server.

The client is met with the following page after trying to upload an image to one of their products.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Input string was not in a correct format.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Input string was not in a correct format.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

            <br><br>

            <b> Exception Details: </b>System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.<br><br>

            <b>Source Error:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code>

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.</code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <b>Stack Trace:</b> <br><br>

            <table width=100% bgcolor="#ffffcc">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                      <code><pre>

[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer&amp; number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +12724149
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +120
   System.Convert.ToInt32(String value) +44
   cms_product_photo.btnCrop_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +207
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9782378
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +204
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1639
</pre></code>

                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>

            <br>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3056.0

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
<!-- 
[FormatException]: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
   at cms_product_photo.btnCrop_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
[HttpUnhandledException]: Exception of type &#39;System.Web.HttpUnhandledException&#39; was thrown.
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.cms_product_photo_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
-->
```

I have downloaded the ASP site from the server trying to resolve the problem in Visual Studio but cannot modify the VB code of the ASP page where the upload is taking place.

Edit

This is the form where the button is found

```html
<!-- END PAGE TITLE & BREADCRUMB-->
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END PAGE HEADER-->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT-->
    <div class="row-fluid">
     <div class="span12">
                        <form id="frmPage" runat="server">
                      <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
         







                           


    <fieldset>
                <div class="widget fluid">
                    <div class="whead"><h3>Photo Upload</h3><div class="clear"></div></div>
                <div class="formRow">
                        <div class="grid3">
    <div>
       <asp:Panel ID="pnlUpload" runat="server">
        <p>Upload a photo. Please ensure the selected photo is in Jpeg (JPG) format and does not exceed more than 2MB in file size. Once you have chosen your photo, click the Upload button to upload your new photo.</p>
        <p>Note: Depending on your internet connection and file size, uploading might take a few seconds to complete.</p>
        <br /><br />
          <asp:FileUpload ID="Upload" runat="server" />
          <p><br /></p>
          <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" Text="Upload"  class="buttonL bGreen"  />
          <asp:Label ID="lblError" runat="server" Visible="false" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlCrop" runat="server" Visible="false">
           
            <p>Please click on the photo and select an area to crop your photo. You may also move the 'view finder' around to select a specific area. Click Crop once you are satisfied with the selected area.</p>
          <asp:Image ID="imgCrop" runat="server"  />
          <br />
          <asp:HiddenField ID="X" runat="server" />
          <asp:HiddenField ID="Y" runat="server" />
            
          <asp:HiddenField ID="W" runat="server" />
          <asp:HiddenField ID="H" runat="server" />

          <asp:Button ID="btnCrop" runat="server" Text="Crop" class="buttonL bGreen"  OnClick="btnCrop_Click" />
      
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlCropped" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <p>Congratulations, your photo was uploaded successfully.  </p>  

            <div style="width: 400px">
                <asp:Image ID="imgCropped" runat="server"  Visible="True" Width="400px" ViewStateMode="Enabled" />
            </div>
            <p><br /></p>
            <h3>Problem with your Photo?</h3>
            <p>You're newly uploaded photo might not show immediately due to your browser caching settings. Click the link below to upload and crop another photo.</p>
             <asp:HyperLink ID="hlinkPhoto" runat="server" class="btn Blue" >Try Again</asp:HyperLink> 


            

        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlProgress" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <div class="PleaseWait">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Please wait...</div>
         </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
   
















                        </form>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END PAGE CONTENT-->
   </div>
   <!-- END PAGE CONTAINER--> 
  </div>
  <!-- END PAGE -->   
 </div>
 <!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

Edit 2 -------

After using .NET Reflector I was able to decode the DLL in which the VB code is of the btnCrop

Here is the code

```html
using AjaxControlToolkit;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Profile;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public class cms_product_photo : Page, IRequiresSessionState
{
    [AccessedThroughProperty("style_color")]
    private HtmlLink _style_color;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Head1")]
    private HtmlHead _Head1;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("lblMemberName")]
    private Label _lblMemberName;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("lblUser")]
    private Label _lblUser;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("ToolkitScriptManager1")]
    private ToolkitScriptManager _ToolkitScriptManager1;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Upload")]
    private FileUpload _Upload;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("btnUpload")]
    private Button _btnUpload;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("lblError")]
    private Label _lblError;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("pnlUpload")]
    private Panel _pnlUpload;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("imgCrop")]
    private System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image _imgCrop;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("X")]
    private HiddenField _X;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("Y")]
    private HiddenField _Y;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("W")]
    private HiddenField _W;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("H")]
    private HiddenField _H;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("btnCrop")]
    private Button _btnCrop;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("pnlCrop")]
    private Panel _pnlCrop;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("imgCropped")]
    private System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image _imgCropped;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("hlinkPhoto")]
    private HyperLink _hlinkPhoto;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("pnlCropped")]
    private Panel _pnlCropped;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("pnlProgress")]
    private Panel _pnlProgress;
    [AccessedThroughProperty("frmPage")]
    private HtmlForm _frmPage;
    private cls_Auth clsAuth;
    public string sUserType;
    private int iId;
    private string path;
    private cls_Auth auth;

    public cms_product_photo()
    {
        base.Load += new EventHandler(this.Page_Load);
        this.clsAuth = new cls_Auth();
        this.path = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "App_Media/Products/";
        this.auth = new cls_Auth();
    }

    protected void btnCrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = this.Session["WorkingImage"].ToString();
        int width = Convert.ToInt32(this.W.Value);
        int height = Convert.ToInt32(this.H.Value);
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(this.X.Value);
        int y = Convert.ToInt32(this.Y.Value);
        try
        {
            File.Delete("App_Media/Products/u_" + Conversions.ToString(this.iId) + ".jpg");
        }
        catch (Exception exception1)
        {
            ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1);
            Exception exception = exception1;
            ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
        }
        byte[] buffer = Crop(this.path + str, width, height, x, y);
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, buffer.Length))
        {
            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream, true))
            {
                string filename = this.path + "u_" + Conversions.ToString(this.iId) + ".jpg";
                image.Save(filename, image.RawFormat);
                this.pnlCrop.Visible = false;
                this.pnlCropped.Visible = true;
                this.imgCropped.ImageUrl = "App_Media/Products/u_" + Conversions.ToString(this.iId) + ".jpg";
            }
        }
        try
        {
            this.InsertPhoto("App_Media/Products/u_" + Conversions.ToString(this.iId) + ".jpg");
            this.imgCropped.ImageUrl = "App_Media/Products/u_" + Conversions.ToString(this.iId) + ".jpg?" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
            this.imgCropped.Width = Conversions.ToInteger("400px");
        }
        catch (Exception exception3)
        {
            ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception3);
            Exception exception2 = exception3;
            ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
        }
        this.hlinkPhoto.NavigateUrl = "cms_product_photo.aspx?Id=" + Conversions.ToString(this.iId);
        File.Delete(Conversions.ToString(Operators.AddObject(this.path, this.Session["WorkingImage"])));
    }

    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        bool flag2 = false;
        this.pnlProgress.Visible = true;
        if (this.Upload.HasFile)
        {
            this.Session["WorkingImage"] = this.Upload.FileName;
            string str = Path.GetExtension(this.Session["WorkingImage"].ToString()).ToLower();
            string[] strArray = new string[] { ".jpeg", ".jpg" };
            int num2 = strArray.Length - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i <= num2; i++)
            {
                if (str == strArray[i])
                {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Upload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Conversions.ToString(Operators.AddObject(this.path, this.Session["WorkingImage"])));
                flag2 = true;
                try
                {
                    File.Delete("App_Media/Products/u_" + Conversions.ToString(this.iId) + ".jpg");
                }
                catch (Exception exception1)
                {
                    ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1);
                    Exception exception = exception1;
                    ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception3)
            {
                ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception3);
                Exception exception2 = exception3;
                this.lblError.Text = "File could not be uploaded." + exception2.Message.ToString();
                this.lblError.Visible = true;
                flag2 = false;
                ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.lblError.Text = "Cannot accept files of this type.";
            this.lblError.Visible = true;
        }
        if (flag2)
        {
            this.pnlUpload.Visible = false;
            this.pnlCrop.Visible = true;
            this.imgCrop.ImageUrl = "App_Media/Products/" + this.Session["WorkingImage"].ToString();
        }
        this.pnlProgress.Visible = false;
    }

    private static byte[] Crop(string Img, int Width, int Height, int X, int Y)
    {
        byte[] buffer;
        try
        {
            using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Img))
            {
                using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Width, Height))
                {
                    bitmap.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);
                    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                    {
                        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                        Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
                        graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, X, Y, Width, Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                        bitmap.Save(stream, image.RawFormat);
                        buffer = stream.GetBuffer();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception1)
        {
            ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1);
            Exception exception = exception1;
            throw exception;
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    private void InsertPhoto(string sPhotoURL)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ToString());
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tbl_Products SET Item_Thumbnail_Image = '" + sPhotoURL + "', Item_Image_1_600 = '" + sPhotoURL + "', Item_Image_1_420 = '" + sPhotoURL + "'  WHERE Id = " + Conversions.ToString(this.iId), connection);
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception exception1)
        {
            ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1);
            Exception exception = exception1;
            ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.iId = Conversions.ToInteger(this.Request.QueryString["Id"]);
        }
        catch (Exception exception1)
        {
            ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1);
            Exception exception = exception1;
            this.Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
            ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
        }
    }

    protected virtual HtmlLink style_color
    {
        get => 
            this._style_color;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._style_color = value);
    }

    protected virtual HtmlHead Head1
    {
        get => 
            this._Head1;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._Head1 = value);
    }

    protected virtual Label lblMemberName
    {
        get => 
            this._lblMemberName;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._lblMemberName = value);
    }

    protected virtual Label lblUser
    {
        get => 
            this._lblUser;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._lblUser = value);
    }

    protected virtual ToolkitScriptManager ToolkitScriptManager1
    {
        get => 
            this._ToolkitScriptManager1;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._ToolkitScriptManager1 = value);
    }

    protected virtual FileUpload Upload
    {
        get => 
            this._Upload;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._Upload = value);
    }

    protected virtual Button btnUpload
    {
        get => 
            this._btnUpload;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._btnUpload = value);
    }

    protected virtual Label lblError
    {
        get => 
            this._lblError;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._lblError = value);
    }

    protected virtual Panel pnlUpload
    {
        get => 
            this._pnlUpload;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._pnlUpload = value);
    }

    protected virtual System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgCrop
    {
        get => 
            this._imgCrop;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._imgCrop = value);
    }

    protected virtual HiddenField X
    {
        get => 
            this._X;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._X = value);
    }

    protected virtual HiddenField Y
    {
        get => 
            this._Y;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._Y = value);
    }

    protected virtual HiddenField W
    {
        get => 
            this._W;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._W = value);
    }

    protected virtual HiddenField H
    {
        get => 
            this._H;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._H = value);
    }

    protected virtual Button btnCrop
    {
        get => 
            this._btnCrop;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._btnCrop = value);
    }

    protected virtual Panel pnlCrop
    {
        get => 
            this._pnlCrop;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._pnlCrop = value);
    }

    protected virtual System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgCropped
    {
        get => 
            this._imgCropped;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._imgCropped = value);
    }

    protected virtual HyperLink hlinkPhoto
    {
        get => 
            this._hlinkPhoto;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._hlinkPhoto = value);
    }

    protected virtual Panel pnlCropped
    {
        get => 
            this._pnlCropped;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._pnlCropped = value);
    }

    protected virtual Panel pnlProgress
    {
        get => 
            this._pnlProgress;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._pnlProgress = value);
    }

    protected virtual HtmlForm frmPage
    {
        get => 
            this._frmPage;
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        set => 
            (this._frmPage = value);
    }

    protected DefaultProfile Profile =>
        ((DefaultProfile) this.Context.Profile);

    protected HttpApplication ApplicationInstance =>
        this.Context.ApplicationInstance;
}
```

Comment: You have shared generated code and you can't fix any error without modifying code.

Comment: Inside stack trace I found `btnCrop_Click` event content causing exception, can you provide contents of corresponding event handler?

Comment: After the btnCrop is clicked I am directly met with the generated code that I supplied

Comment: The most suspicious part in `btnCrop_Click` method are integer conversions, such like `Convert.ToInt32`. Try debug code-behind source and see in which integer conversion the exception has thrown (also current string value to convert).